# File Upload with Rackspace

Tags: c#, file-upload, restsharp, rackspace, cloudfiles

I'm using RestSharp to consume the Rackspace restful API [here](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Create_Update_Object-d1e1965.html). The documentation shows you how to create the request but I don't see where do I need to specify the data source(file I want to upload to rackspace).

```
  PUT /<api version>/<account>/<container>/<object> HTTP/1.1
  Host: storage.clouddrive.com
  X-Auth-Token: eaaafd18-0fed-4b3a-81b4-663c99ec1cbb
  ETag: 8a964ee2a5e88be344f36c22562a6486
  Content-Length: 512000
  X-Object-Meta-PIN: 1234
```

This is how I'm creating the request:

```
string cloudPath = MainContainerName + "/"  + file + "." + "wav";
string localPath =  Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Audio/Clean"), file + ".wav");

byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(localPath);

RackUserAuthToken authUser = CloudLib.RackAuth.AuthenticateUser(userName, userPassword);

//Request

var containers = new RObject();
string svAddress =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RackSpaceStorage"];

var restClient = new RestClient();
restClient.BaseUrl = svAddress;
var request = new RestRequest(cloudPath, Method.PUT);
request.AddHeader("X-Auth-Token", authUser.AuthToken);
//request.AddHeader("ETag", localPath);
request.AddHeader("Content-Length",data.Length.ToString());
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
var response = restClient.Execute(request);
```

The response is:

```
[{
"bytes": 0,
"content_type": "audio\/x-wav",
"hash": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
"last_modified": "2012-08-29T17:21:23.423150",
"name": "newTest.wav"
}]
```

So the file gets created but there is nothing in the file, since the size is 0 bytes.

Any help is greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
request.AddFile(localPath);
```

from http://restsharp.org/